# Not able to read the value of an input properly

Tags: javascript, html, numbers, nan

I am a newbie in JavaScript and I was learning to create a simple calculator using JavaScript and HTML.

I have two inputs `Fld1` and `Fld2`. When I enter values in the input, it should be added up. But when I am calling the values in JavaScript, it returns 'NaN' for both inputs even if I have parsed them into numbers.

```
<input type="number" name="NumberField1" id="Fld1" placeholder="0" required>
<input type="number" name="NumberField2" id="Fld2" placeholder="0" required>
```

```
let num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Fld1").value);
let num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Fld2").value);
let output = num1 + num2;
```

I want the `output` to be the sum of `num1` and `num2`.

What am I doing wrong? What should I try? Please help me...

I tried adding a default value tag in it `value="0"`. But when I am doing so, the value is 0 even if I am entering a different number.

```
<input type="number" name="NumberField1" id="Fld1" value="0" placeholder="0" required>
<input type="number" name="NumberField2" id="Fld2" value="0" placeholder="0" required>
```

I even tried changing the input type, removing the placeholder and changing the value to 0 `onfocus="this.value = '';`. Nothing worked!

Help me out!

Full Code

```html
    <body>
        <main>
            <h1>Calculator</h1>
                <div id="right">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <div id="inputs">
                            <input type="number" name="NumberField1" 
    id="Fld1" placeholder="0" required>
                            <input type="number" name="NumberField2" 
    id="Fld2" placeholder="0" required>
                        </div>
                        <button id="equals" 
    onclick="Submit()">&equals;</button>
                        <div id="output">
                            <hr>
                            <span>0</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>


        <script>
            let num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Fld1").value);
            let num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Fld2").value);
            function Submit() {
              document.querySelector("#output > span").innerHTML = num1 + num2;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Problem is not reproducible. Maybe you can add a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) in your question with the reproducible problem. By the way, you don't need to add `parseFloat` when you are already defining the type of `input` as `number`.

Comment: @PK_ No, it's returning **string** even if I have used `input type="number"`

Comment: Ok. Here is the [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/vbrhnfje/) of your code. You did not define the `Submit()` function anywhere that you are calling `onclick`. I have wrapped your js code in script tag inside the `Submit()` function. Also added `parseFloat()` to input values. You can see the result in console.

Comment: Thank you. I had to define the variables inside the function. I wasted 4 hours on this little mistake... by the way, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the script runs before the change of the input values.
Move the calculation into the `Submit` function

```html
        <body>
        <main>
            <h1>Calculator</h1>
                <div id="right">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <div id="inputs">
                            <input type="number" name="NumberField1" 
    id="Fld1" placeholder="0" required>
                            <input type="number" name="NumberField2" 
    id="Fld2" placeholder="0" required>
                        </div>
                        <button id="equals" 
    onclick="Submit()">&equals;</button>
                        <div id="output">
                            <hr>
                            <span>0</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>


        <script>
            function Submit() {
            let num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Fld1").value);
            let num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Fld2").value);
              document.querySelector("#output > span").innerHTML = num1 + num2;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because value of variable only update once at the time of page load. it should be update every time when you invoke submit button. move below lines inside the submit button

```
let num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Fld1").value);
let num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Fld2").value);
```